# Is there a way to fetch only the rows that are modified using the google sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to ingest some data from google sheets into a warehouse and don't want to read the entire file every time. Is there a way to only fetch the modified rows without changing the source sheet?

Comment: You can save the index of the last row processed and afterwards, using the API, only select the rows below it. Would that work for you? Cheers

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply! You're right, that would work for any new rows that were added but it wouldn't help if any of the already ingested rows itself were modified. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not possible. There exists a [revisions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) for drive files, however, it can only export the whole file and not limit it to modified rows only.

If you still want to implement this feature, I suggest you check out [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). Using it, you could implement a solution that:

1. Detects when a row is modified (using an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger).
2. After detecting it, it can copy the whole, modified row into another Sheet or Spreadsheet (see [Range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)).
3. That sheet/spreadsheet would be the one used for the ingestion of your application. After it is ingested, it could be cleaned up (or the index of the last ingested row could be locally saved, as previously mentioned).